# Call python descriptor's __get__ with additional arguments?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-descriptors

Is it possible to pass additional arguments when getting a descriptor?

For example, I'd like to have:

```
class Element(object):
    def __init__(self, text='initial'):
        self.text = text

    def __get__(self, instance, owner, extra_text=''):
        print self.text + instance.name + extra_text
```

And then be able to use it like:

```
class MyClass(object):
    elem1 = Element()
    elem2 = Element(text='override')

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def print_elems(self):
        self.elem1
        self.elem1(extra_text='extra')
        self.elem2
        self.elem2(extra_text='extra')

MyClass('name').print_elems()
```

And then get:

```
initialname
initialnameextra
overridename
overridenameextra
```

Is there any way to make this work? I've even tried calling `elem1.__get__(self, self.__class__, extra_text='extra)` and making `extra_text` a required param, but couldn't figure out any way to actually provide it?

If not with descriptors, is there an alternative way to achieve this syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, if you change it slightly to `self.elem1()` and `self.elem1(extra_text='extra')` you basically have reinvented a method.  AFAIK it may be possible but I would **never** do that.

Comment: You definitely can't do it that way, because descriptors only work when accessed as attributes (like `self.elem1`, not plain `elem1`).  What you can do is make the descriptor's `__get__` return a callable object that accepts whatever arguments you want.  But what are you trying to do that you can't do with an ordinary method?

Comment: @BrenBarn my mistake, I meant to have `self`! The main thing I was trying to do was get the instance in the descriptor class without having to pass it by param.

Comment: @Bakuriu: I'm okay with the `self.elem1()` syntax, but what I was trying to avoid with descriptors was having to passing `self` every time rather than just being able to use `instance`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to call **get**() with anything but the automatic arguments, you need to access the instance of the descriptor. To do that...
Step 1: add as the first line to **get**():

```
if instance is None:
    return self
```

This is a fairly common addition to the method.

Step 2: When accessing the descriptor, get it from the class instead of the instance:

```
MyClass.elem1
MyClass.elem1
```

or

```
type(my_inst).elem1
type(my_inst).elem1
```

Step 3: Call **get** () explicitly, passing in the desired argument.

Ugly and verbose; avoid as long as you can.

I've got a book released about descriptors, which can be found at http://www.lulu.com/spotlight/jacobz_20
It can really help you wrap your head around this if you're confused.